# Working with simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've loaded my file using the following commands:

```
$feed = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'\1.txt');  
$items = simplexml_load_string($feed);
```

How can I build an xml out of it so I'll be able to use commands like:
$xml->bbb ( where bbb is a node name)
Also how can I retrieve all the children nodes of a specific node.

Thanks

Comment: And what is your problem/question ?

Comment: $y = $items->children();
echo $y;

Comment: On the other hand when doing  `echo $items->asXML()`  I get the xml info but not structured ...

Comment: Add `header ("Content-Type:text/xml");` at the top and it is nice structured.

Comment: @Rizier123: Can you please explain How can I add header by function to the given objects above?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

All children you can get using *children* function, for example:

```
$items->children();
```

Then you can iterate over all children using foreach loop.

If you mean how to get value of a child bbb it was simple:

```
$items->bbb->__toString();
```